# Good websites to help improve usage of prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Please anyone suggest some good websites which give tips on the usage of prepositions on a daily or weekly basis.

I have doubts regarding usage of prepositions in many contexts. So wanted to know a general website which would help.

I am a software programmer and i get many doubts regarding the usage of prepsitions many times while discussing on forums.

For example: I am not sure of a sentence like 
"Is this conference only for android developers or anyone without a prior knowledge of/in android coding can attend? "

Comment: A possible approach is to Google both phrases, e.g. "knowledge of coding" and "knowledge in coding", and see what occurs more often.

Answer (score 2):

you may like this:
http://rwc.hunter.cuny.edu/reading-writing/on-line/prep-def.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also search [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/) for your questions.